# How can I make reference to fields in VBA and determine value for them from another fields?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm used to do the same work on documents pattern every day. I've got to calculate the difference between two dates and then write it on the doc.

How could I code a fast model to input a date and then calculate the difference from this date to Now and then auto input the result in the fields?

I've tried to use InputBox for this, but I'm having trouble to determine the value like I'm used to do in Excel, where the objects Cell or Range are both in and outputs for Value.

Set myRange = Selection.Fields(1).Result 
' I wanted to do somthing like this:
ActiveDocument.Field(1) = DiffDate("d", Now, DER) & " days."

Comment: You don't provide enough information to understand exactly what you want to do. What kind of "field"? Word has tens of various kinds of field. In what way does `DiffDate` not work for you? Provide some examples of what you've tried, the result you get and how it differs from what you want. You can use the [edit] link below the question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is unclear. If you want to use a field's result for the calculation, you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
MsgBox DateDiff("d", Now(), ActiveDocument.Fields(1).Result)
End Sub
```

Writing to a field's result is unreliable, as whatever you've written will be lost immediately the field is refreshed; you should write to a bookmark, table cell, or content control instead. You could even write to a formfield in a document with 'filling in forms' protection applied. To write to a bookmark, you might use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range.Text = DateDiff("d", "1/1/2000", Now())
End Sub
```